# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error: "openai.createChatCompletion is not a function"

Tags: axios, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have this in my MERN stack code file, and it works well.

```
exports.chatbot = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("OpenAI Chatbot Post");

  const { textInput } = req.body;

  try {

    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
      model: "text-davinci-003",
      prompt: `
            What is your name?
            My name is Chatbot.
            How old are you?
            I am 900 years old.
            ${textInput}`,
      max_tokens: 100,
      temperature: 0,
    });
    if (response.data) {
      if (response.data.choices[0].text) {
        return res.status(200).json(response.data.choices[0].text);
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

While I change the API request, use the new API for chat completion, This one doesn't work(the API code is from openAI website, and works on postman)

```
exports.chatbot = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("OpenAI Chatbot Post");

  const { textInput } = req.body;

  try {
    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [{ role: "user", content: textInput }],
    });
    console.log(completion.data.choices[0].message);

    if (completion.data) {
      if (completion.data.choices[0].message) {
        return res.status(200).json(completion.data.choices[0].message);
      }
    }

  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

the error message:

POST http://localhost:3000/api/openai/chatbot 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinstall the openai npm package. It has only just been updated with the createChatCompletion in the past 2 days.

When I reinstalled the package and ran your code it worked successfully.

Comment: Oh, you are a life saver, I looked into the codes for hours and never realize that I need to reinstall the package. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

You need to upgrade the OpenAI package.

**Python:**

`pip install --upgrade openai`

**NodeJS:**

`npm update openai`

Close the terminal and open it again. Run the code. The error should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you used npm to install openai for nodejs, you may need the following syntax:

```
this.openai.chat.completions.create({
  model: "gpt-3.5-turbo", ...
```

I got this syntax from the npm site for the framework which made sense in retrospect:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai

Note: I started by testing my api calls in the OpenAI playground and took the code generated by the site, but that did not work for me.